# Using JSON as config in flashembed of jQuery Tools

Tags: flash, json, parameters, embed, jquery-tools

jQuery Tools has flashembed which can pass a JSON object as a config parameter to the embedding Flash object. See [the official page](http://flowplayer.org/tools/flashembed.html).

But it does not tell exactly how to get the JSON object in Flash. And that's the question... How??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML and JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){               
        $("#flashPlacement").flashembed(
            {
                src:"Main.swf"
            },
            {   //flashvars
                myJsonObj:
                {
                    someString:"string",
                    someNumber:123,
                    someOtherObj:
                    {
                        someString:"string2",
                        someNumber:456
                    }
                }
            }
        );
        $("#flashPlacement *").show();
    });
</script>
```

In the Flash part, I used [Casalib](http://casalib.org/)'s FlashVarUtil. But yes, what Christopher W. Allen-Poole said (`loaderInfo.parameters.myJsonObj`) will do the job too. (up voted for that)

It will be a `String` in JSON, that's the part I couldn't figure out when asking the question.

AS3:

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSONDecoder;
import org.casalib.util.FlashVarUtil;
import org.casalib.util.StageReference;

StageReference.setStage(stage);
var jsonString:String = FlashVarUtil.getValue("myJsonObj");

//use as3corelib's JSONDecoder
//http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/
var obj:Object = new JSONDecoder(jsonString).getValue();

//now it can be used like...
trace(obj.someOtherObj.someString); //output: string2
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on whether you are in AS2 or AS3.  I believe AS2 simply sets the variables on the _root, but I could be mistaken.  In AS3, you will need to go to your root.loaderInfo.parameters object.  All of the variables are stored there in key/value pairs.

Eg:

```
myAS2Swf.swf?example=72&other="Quack"

// in the swf:
trace( _root.example ); // 72
trace( _root.other   ); // Quack

// in AS3

myAS3Swf.swf?example=42&other="Duck"    

// in the swf:
trace( root.loaderInfo.parameters.example ); // 42
trace( root.loaderInfo.parameters.other   ); // Duck
```